# Pyspark: Error in reduce by Key;IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, rdd

Below is my code for rdd:

```
temp_var = temp_var.map(lambda x: (x[0], ((x[1][2]*x[1][3])+ x[1][0],x[1] [1]+x[1][2])))
print(temp_var.take(10))
```

Which gives the output as  :

```
[(0, (0.001622198104049003, 0.0003244396208098006)), (0, (0.001589754141968023, 0.0003244396208098006)), (0, (0.004704374501742109, 0.0003244396208098006)), (0, (0.08587896987089527, 0.0103468638398669)), (0, (0.1511040100829534, 0.017988572628923026)), (0, (-0.33229466944785196, 0.36921629938650213)), (0, (0.006951662718310904, 0.0013368582150597892)), (0, (-0.01002643661294842, 0.0013368582150597892)), (0, (0.01832857525662582, 0.0012998989543706256)), (0, (0.022748231702761298, 0.0012998989544435028))]
```

I am trying to reduce the two columns of rdd by summing it up as follows:

```
# this lambda is not working
temp_var = temp_var.reduceByKey(lambda w, y: ((w[0] + y[0],w[1]+y[1])))
```

But instead, it is throwing error as :

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Have been trying for long time. Can someone let me know whats wrong ?

Comment: If I had to guess, somewhere in one of your rows one of the elements is a string. Try: printing out `temp_var.filter(lambda row: len(row[1]) < 2).take(10)` to check for bad data.

Comment: @pault thanks. It was indeed a bad kind of key which i selected. Thanks for quickly responding.